# indicator-multiload (System Load Indicator) don't show cpu usage correctly

Tags: indicator, settings, cpu, system-settings

I have accidentally deleted CPU usage percentage from indicator-multiload menu and now I can't remember what it syntax looks like and can't go back to how it was.

- **Possibility 1 (simplest one).** Can someone who currently use idicator-multiload and have CPU usage displayed go to Preferences **-->** Menu items... and paste these few lines in answer?
- **Possibility 2.** Does anyone know where idicator-multiload stores config file/s. I cant find it in ~/.config ? `sudo apt-get purge indicator-multiload` evidently didn't removed configuration file, I have executed it and then reinstalled package with `sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload` and it restored my (broken) settings.
- **Possibility 3.** Does anyone simply know the correct syntax wich displays e.g. CPU 34%, iowait [something]?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you need:

*from system load indicator:*

CPU: $(percent(cpu.inuse)), iowait $(percent(cpu.io))

Comment: Yes, this is just what I need. :)